# The function can't be unconditionally invoked because it can be 'null'. ZStack.clip()

Tags: flutter, dart

This piece of code is from pre-null safety version of flutter. It uses VelocityX, which I know is kind of depriciated, but I am trying to make it work by modifying it.

```
"radios": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "92.7",
    "tagline": "Suno Sunao, Life Banao!",
    "color": "0xffa11431",
    "desc": "The chills you get when you listen to music, is mostly caused by the brain releasing dopamine while anticipating the peak moment of a song.",
    "url": "http://sc-bb.1.fm:8017/;",
    "icon": "https://mytuner.global.ssl.fastly.net/media/tvos_radios/m8afyszryaqt.png",
    "image": "https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/project_modules/max_1200/b5df4c18876369.562d0d4bd94cf.jpg",
    "lang": "Hindi",
    "category": "pop",
    "disliked": false,
    "order": 1
  },
...
]
```

```
final rad = radios![index];
ZStack? Z = ZStack([
  Positioned(
    top: 0.0,
    right: 0.0,
    child: VxBox(
      child:  rad.category.text.uppercase.white.make().p16(),
    ).height(40).color(Colors.black).alignCenter.withRounded(value: 10.0).make(),

  ),

  Align(
    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
    child: VStack([
      rad.name.text.xl3.white.bold.make(),
      5.heightBox,
      rad.tagline.text.sm.white.semiBold.make(),
    ],
      crossAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    ),
  ),
  Align(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    child: [const Icon(
      CupertinoIcons.play_circle,
      color: Colors.white,
    ),
      10.heightBox,
      "Double tap to play".text.gray300.make()
    ].vStack(),
  ),
]).clip(Clip.antiAlias);
```

Everything works fine except the last line, that is `.clip(Clip.antiAlias)`

It gives the following error: [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtsnJ.png)

It works fine if I remove `.clip(Clip.antiAlias)` .

I resolved a similar error previously

```
itemCount: radios?.length ?? 0,
```

and it worked.

But `ZStack Z1 = Z?.clip(Clip.antiAlias) ?? Z` , where Z does not have .clip() method, does not work. Even ! null check does not work.

Is there any work-around for this ? Or any best practice I am missing ?

Comment: VelocityX seems to be a current package although I have no experience of it.

Answer (score 0):

please add ! null check operator before .clip()

solution for your problem is ->

```
ZStack Z1 = Z!.clip(Clip.antiAlias) ?? Z
```

where Z must be some other object incase if you object return null